# Cannot open/access ports on Ubuntu

Tags: apache-httpd, ipv4, port

I created an Apache web server on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, using the guide described [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart). Afterwards the web server worked completely fine.

Later on I installed [Libvirt](https://libvirt.org/) onto the web server, after which the web server stopped working. So i uninstalled it along with the "virbr0" network bridge it created.

The web server still did not work afterwards so I used `sudo netstat -nap` and found that apache2 was unable to bind/access port 80 on IPv4 but it was able to on IPv6.

How do I allow apache2 to have access to port 80 on IPv4?

Comment: Does `systemctl status apache2.service` give any clue?

Comment: No. It shows the same output as before when the web server was working correctly; Active and running correctly